# Handling variables in function with parallel spawning in Python

Tags: python, parallel-processing, simulation, montecarlo

I have a Monte Carlo simulator that has a calculation function it calls many (millions or more) times in a loop.  In order to speed this up, I would like split it into multiple parallel thread calls to the simulator.  ie.  If I want a to run it a total of 1 million times, split it up into maybe 4 - 250,000 runs all going in parallel.  With each thread using the same variable names, how do I handle this so there are no clashes?  Do I have to create 4 seperate versions of my simulator with differently named variables?

I have started to write a version using the Python threading module, but am certain there will still be issues with the variables.

Any suggestions?

Thanks for your time.

Kyle

Comment: I don't really know what the simulation is about but if it's (for example) using one list item in each iteration you could split it by using offsets, i.e. `thread 1: f(m[x]), thread 2: f(m[x+1]), ... thread n: f(m[x+(n-1)])` and then increment `x` by number of threads `x += n`. Also, consider using [cython](http://cython.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your code is pure Python, and you are using CPython, threading likely won't speed up your code due to the [global interpreter lock](http://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock).  What you are probably looking for is the [`multiprocessing` module](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html), specifically its [`Pool.map()` method](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.map).

Since using `mulitprocessing` means using separate processes instead of just separate threads, things like locking will become much less an issue.

That said, vectorising your code using NumPy or writing the inner loop in an efficient compiled language like C or Cython are likely to give you much more speed-up than parallelising it to four cores.

Comment: I agree that converting to NumPy will give a speedup. But adding parallellization should be able to offer great speedups as well. No reason not use both!

Comment: I am using standard pure Python, so I guess that is also known as CPython.
I all ready use NumPy and read up a bit on vectorization but still don't fully understand it.  As my simulation is basically about 15 calculations involving Physics that is fairly linear (ie. the next equation relies on the previous), I am not sure I would be up for working out all those dependancies. 

I never heard of Cython, but will start reading up on it and Pool.map.

Thank you for your advice and I will let you know how it works out.

Comment: I got it!
My solution was using multiprocessing, as suggested, although I didn't use the pool.map() method.  Simply making calls to a class that is a modified version of the multiprocessing.Process object based on the number of cores I wish to load-up, I can get what I wanted. I have fully learned the anoyance of the GIL, by writing a full multithread version as well, and how multiprocessing solves that.
Thank you for your advice!!